# Vector comparison with string

Tags: c++, vector, comparison

I have a string vector of user-input data containing strings. Now I need to make sure program won't execute if strings are different than specified few. Vector contains 4 fields and every has different condition:

- vector[0] can only be "1" or "0"

  vector[1] can only be "red" or "green

  vector[2] can only be "1", "2" or "3"

  vector[3] can only be "1" or "0"

I tried writing if for every condition:

```
if(tokens[0]!="1" || tokens[0]!="0"){
    decy = "error";
}
else if(tokens[1]!="red" || tokens[1]!="green"){
    decy = "error";
}
else if(tokens[2]!="1" || tokens[2]!="2" || tokens[2]!="3"){
    decy = "error";
}
else if(tokens[3]!="1" || tokens[3]!="0"){
    decy = "error";
}
else{
switch(){} //working code
}
return decy;
```

It always enters first if and returns error. I tried with *if* instead of *else if* but it doesn't work either. I checked `vector[i]` contents and it returns correct strings. No " " at the end of it etc. Removing *else* and releasing switch just makes program check first condition and ignore rest of it.

I'm probably doing something terribly wrong, but I can't find an answer on internet so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions are invalid.

**Any** distinct value can satisfy your conditions.

You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

For example:

```
if (tokens[0] != "1" || tokens[0] != "0") {
```

Consider this line. If `tokens[0]` is `"1"`, which is valid input, it will not satisfy the first condition, but it will satisfy the second. You only want to throw an error when the value is neither of the valid possible inputs.

This means that your condition should be:

```
if (tokens[0] != "1" && tokens[0] != "0") {
```

Same goes for all the others.

Comment: Wow, looks like I really need a rest.
It works now, thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if(tokens[0]!="1" || tokens[0]!="0")
```

should be:

```
if(tokens[0]!="1" && tokens[0]!="0")
                  ^^
```

The same goes for the rest of the `if` statements as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should turn those `||` into `&&`. If the input can only be `X` or `Y`, this means that it is illegal when it is not `X` *and* not `Y`:

```
if (tokens[0] != "1" && tokens [0] !="0")
//                   ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if:

```
if(tokens[0]!="1" || tokens[0]!="0")
```

ALWAYS evaluates to `true`.